# Php regex change a decimal number between special characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace a decimal number between 2 decoded html characters. I know I need to use regex for this but couldn't write it properly.
my string:

```
$string = 'class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;5.00&lt;/td&gt;';
```

What I need to change is 5.00 with another decimal number.

I've tried that:

```
$string = 'class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;5.00&lt;/td&gt;';
$new_number = 7.00;
echo preg_replace('#\class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;(.+?)\&lt;/td&gt;#', $new_number, $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;5.00&lt;/td&gt;';
$replacement = '6.00';
echo preg_replace('/(class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;)(\d+\.\d{1,2})(&lt;\/td&gt;)/', '${1}' . $replacement . '${3}', $string);
```

The other answer won't work in most cases, the replacement won't work as it will try to access $17 capture which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
$re = '/(class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;)([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)(&lt;\/td&gt;)/';
$str = 'class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;5.00&lt;/td&gt;';
$subst = '${1}7.00${3}';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
$string = 'class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;5.00&lt;/td&gt;';
$new_number = 7.00;
echo preg_replace('#(?=class=&quot;total&quot;&gt;).+?(?=&lt;/td&gt;)#', $new_number, $string);
```